# mysql query to update all values +1 where value is less than 100

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
create table `test` 
(
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `value` smallint (3) NOT NULL,
```

I am trying to make a `mysql` query that increment every `row` in the `test` table where `value` is less than 100.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
update test set value=value+1 where value < 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update table set value = (value + 1) where column <= 100;
```